# SQL Deleting rows based on two or more columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to delete from my table all rows where the 'ID' column is NULL, except for the rows where the the 'group column is 'Everyone'. How can I do this? I have tried different combinations of the above query and none of them have worked.

```
delete from LANReporter where NOT [Group] = 'everyone' AND [ID] IS NULL AND 
[Server] = 'sv73938'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Group` can be NULL you need to do this:

```
WHERE (Group IS NULL OR [Group] <> 'everyone') AND [ID] IS NULL AND 
[Server] = 'sv73938'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Not Equal To" condition `!=`:

```
  DELETE FROM LANReporter 
  WHERE [Group] != 'everyone'
      AND [ID] IS NULL
      AND [Server] = 'sv73938';
```

If this still doesn't do the trick, then I suspect you have issues in your data (perhaps your NULL's aren't actually NULL but rather empty strings, or whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

`delete from LANReporter where [id] is null and [group] not in ('everyone') and [Server] = 'sv73938';`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
delete LANReporter where [Group] <> 'everyone' AND [ID] IS NULL AND 
[Server] = 'sv73938'
```